# How to align a tikz column next to an empty column

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wanted to align three columns using 'right of', and used \phantom{} to place an item next to an empty position. However, that element appears shifted. What is wrong with using \phantom here? I guess I should use something like \phantom[node]. Is there something similar?
(   \phantom{\node (X2M) [ right of=X2]     {$L_3$};}
gives the same result.

OK, I found an approximate solution, but I modify the question. From 'node distance~ I guessed that something like center, or leftmost position, etc. will be aligned, so I can place my object like using a grid. Am I wrong?

[image]

```
\documentclass[english,14pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{tikz}   
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=1.5cm,
                     semithick]
   \tikzstyle{every state}=[scale=0.75]
   \node[state]  (L3)                    {$L_3$};
   \node[state]  (L4) [ below of=L3]     {$L_3$};

   \node[state]  (X1) [ left of=L3]     {$X_1$};
   \node         (XM) [ below of=X1]     {};
   \node[state]  (X2) [ below of=XM]     {$X_2$};

   \node (X2M) [ right of=X2]     {\phantom{$L_3$}};

   \node         (C3) [ right of=L3] {$Cycle\ 3$};
   \node         (C4) [ right of=L4] {$Cycle\ 4$};
   \node         (C5) [ right of=X2M] {$Cycle\ 5$};

  \path 
    (L3) edge [bend right] (X2)
    (L4) edge  (X2);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass[english,14pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,positioning}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth', semithick, shorten >=1pt,
      auto,
      node distance = 1.5cm and 1.5cm,
 every state/.style = {scale=0.75}
                     ]
% middle column
\node[state]  (L3)                      {$L_3$};
\node[state]  (L4)  [below=of L3]       {$L_3$};
% left column
\node[state]  (X1)  [left= of L3]       {$X_1$};
\node[state]  (X2)  [below left=of L4]  {$X_2$};
% labels
\node   (C3) [right=of L3]              {\emph{Cycl} 3};
\node   (C4) [right=of L4]              {\emph{Cycl} 4};
\node   (C5) [right=of L3.east |- X2]   {\emph{Cycl} 5};
%
\path   (L3) edge [bend right] (X2)
        (L4) edge  (X2);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I add tikzlibrary `positioning`  and by its help eliminate needs for phantom node. With proper defined `node distance` the all nodes are positioned whery you like to be. Similarly, in the right column is aligned to coordinate defined by `L3.east |- X2` and again "phantom" node is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for bothering you.

> \phantom{\node[state] (X2M) [ right of=X2]     {$L_3$};}

works.

Comment: I encourage you to consider solution, where phantom node is surplus.